# backbonejs fire event after parse is complete

Tags: backbone.js

I have this collection with an over-riden `parse` method. I want a method in my view to be called when the collection is finished with `parse`

This collection will be calling `sync` and so `parse` only once.

I tried `this.collection.on("reset", this.more, this);` but that doesn't work.

```
more: function() {
        var users = this.collection.slice( this.index, this.index + this.load_once), that = this;
        this.index = this.index + this.load_once;
        _.each( users, function( user ){
            that.addOne( user );
        });
    },
addOne: function( user ){
    var view = new UserView({model: user});
    this.$("#user_list").append(view.render().el);
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the content of `this.more` ?

Comment: In my view's `initialize`, where I called `this.collection.fetch()`, I passed a function for the `success` option. This works for me.

Answer (score 1):

The reset method will be triggered when `{reset: true}` option is passed to the fetch. You can listen to the `add` and `sync` that will fire this method. Also use `this.listenTo` bind the events in a cleaner manner.

```
initialize: function() {
    ...  some other code
    this.listenTo(this.collection, "add sync", this.more);
    this.collection.fetch();
}
```